# How to use Port 0x03C8 to manipulate Assembly VGA Pallete to show differences in colors?

Tags: assembly, x86

I have a project in assembly (x86) to create a game.  The game tests your ability to see  differences in colors.  I have drawn a matrix (4*4) and filled it with arbitrary color.  Now I want to fill one of the cells [of the matrix] with the same color but brighter.  I need 3 levels of brightness.

I know that I need to use port 03c8, but how to use this port?  Where is the combined color is saved?

Comment: Your question isn't all that clear. What is the screen you're using? Is "one cell" a sixteenth of the "matrix" or just a pixel? Why use ports? Can't you use the BIOS for that?

Comment: graphic node - DOSBOX

Comment: yes, is a sixteenth of a "matrix"

Comment: Still missing a crucial info. Why not use video BIOS function AH=10h AL=10h to SetIndividualColorRegister?

Comment: VGA pallete: so you are using the 13h mode, 320x200 @256 palette colors? Or some other? What means matrix filled by arbitrary color, like every square of 4x4 matrix is filled by color i (1 .. 16), or every square is filled by the same color (then you have to draw particular square with different palette index, so you will not change whole matrix by setting new palette). If you use the direct port to set up palette, the colors are stored (and combined) in the VGA card (IIRC they can be read back trough some port again, maybe the same one). You can't access them in memory.

Comment: I personally would probably draw the matrix with 1..16 colors (or any other startColor to startColor+15), and then I would change the display just by setting those 16 colors (all to the same value except the desired square index to the brighter/darker one). So I wouldn't have to redraw the pixels any more (if the screen part with matrix is static all the time and nothing is changed there) and I would do just palette changes.

Answer (score 2):

"how to use port 03c8 VGA palette guide" -> google ->

http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/ug/graphics/vga.html

search "palette" ->

```
   void set_color(int color, int red, int green, int blue)
   {
      outportb(0x3C8, color);
      outportb(0x3C9, red);
      outportb(0x3C9, green);
      outportb(0x3C9, blue);
   }
```

> The red, green, and blue color values range from 0 up to 63, so for
>   example calling set_color(10, 0, 0, 0) will change color number 10 to
>   black, while set_color(10, 63, 63, 63) would change it to white, and
>   set_color(10, 63, 40, 0) changes it to a shade of orange.